# SOAP implicit headers

Tags: web-services, soap, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I want to add a custom implicit soap header to my response.

**MsqFlow**:

[image]

**ESQL**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        SET OutputRoot.MQMD = InputRoot.MQMD;
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN 'SOAP' NAME 'SOAP';
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.messageId = UUIDASCHAR;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.transactionId = Environment.Variables.Generic.Session.TransactionId;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.correlationId = Environment.Variables.Generic.Session.CorrelationId;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.scrSystem = 'EAI';
        SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC = InputRoot.XMLNSC;
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

in breakpoint between [Compute Node] & [SOAP Reply] in message is filled SOAP with correct parameters, but in response is still see only soap body with no header.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I didn't created XMLNSC and didn't add SOAP Body which is mandatory.

**Final code**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        SET OutputRoot.MQMD = InputRoot.MQMD;
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN 'XMLNSC' NAME 'XMLNSC';
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.messageId = UUIDASCHAR;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.transactionId = Environment.Variables.Generic.Session.TransactionId;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.correlationId = Environment.Variables.Generic.Session.CorrelationId;
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Header.eaie:apiHeader.scrSystem = 'EAI';
        SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Body.nsOut:getXXXResponse = InputRoot.XMLNSC.nsOut:getXXXResponse;
        SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC = InputRoot.XMLNSC;
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

Comment: I think you don't need to create XMLNSC domain, because your answer in this line
`SET OutputRoot.SOAP.Body.nsOut:getXXXResponse = InputRoot.XMLNSC.nsOut:getXXXResponse;`